# Show ratio for all available resolutions

Tags: bash, text-processing, resolution, arithmetic

I tried to get the ratio with this script:

```
echo "$(xrandr)"|cut -f 4 -d" "|sed 's/x/00 \\\* /g'|while read i; do echo "$i = "$(expr $i); done
```

but I get errors like

```
102400 * 768 = 
expr: Syntaxerror
```

I tried changing the amounts or backslashes before `*` but I can't get this to work.

How can I pass the result to `expr` correctly?

desired output:

```
3200x1800 1.77
2048x1536 1.33
1920x1440 1.33
1856x1392 1.33
1792x1344 1.60
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for `echo`, no need for other other useless commands, single `awk` should do the job:

```
$ xrandr | awk -F'[x ]' '/^   /{print $4"x"$5" \t"$4/$5}'

1024x600    1.70667
800x600     1.33333
640x480     1.33333
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
xrandr | awk '/^ +[0-9]/ {gsub(/x/,"/"); print $1}' | bc -l
```

Comment: something like it, but how do I list the reolution before each result?

Answer (score 1):

As a start ...

```
xrandr | awk -F ' *|x' '/^ +[0-9]/{printf("%5sx%-6s %.2f\n", $2, $3, $2 / $3)}'
 1920x1080   1.78
 1680x1050   1.60
 1600x900    1.78
 1280x1024   1.25
 1280x960    1.33
 1280x800    1.60
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I had to devide instead of multiply, so the error causing asterisk is gone.

This works whithout `awk` and `bc`:

```
xrandr|egrep "x[[:digit:]]+ "|cut -f 4 -d" "|sed 's/x/00 \/ /g'|while read i; do echo "$i = "$(expr $i); done
```

my result (selected in the console with CTRL hold):

```
3200 / 1800 = 1.77
2048 / 1536 = 1.33
1920 / 1440 = 1.33
1856 / 1392 = 1.33
1792 / 1344 = 1.33
1920 / 1200 = 1.60
1920 / 1080 = 1.77
1600 / 1200 = 1.33
1680 / 1050 = 1.60
1600 / 1024 = 1.56
1400 / 1050 = 1.33
1280 / 1024 = 1.25
1440 / 900 = 1.600
1280 / 960 = 1.333
1360 / 768 = 1.770
1152 / 864 = 1.333
1024 / 768 = 1.333
800 / 600 = 1.3333
640 / 480 = 1.3333
```